# xhttp is not defined when using ajax calls into an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iframe

Good day all, I'm developing a php page in which there is an iframe, that opens another php page with a checkbox in it, this second page, when the user click on the checkbox, has to make an ajax call to confirm the "click".

so there is pageA.php, with a iframe in it that points to pageB.php, in this one, there is only a form with a checkbox and a javascript (vanilla javascript), that sould call a third page on click.

this is the javascript I'm using to send the "click":

```
document.getElementById("checkboxMe").onclick = function() {
    xhttp.open("POST", "pageC.php", true);
    xhttp.send("foo=bar");  
    };
```

when clicking on the checkbox, this is what I see on the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: xhttp is not defined
```

it never happen something like this, infact I can't find this error easily on google, does anyone has some clues? 
maybe is the fact I'm into an iframe?
how could I solve this issue?

thanks in advance ppl.

Comment: Well where do you define `xhttp`?

Comment: you are right, and I'm a dumb :O

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`xhttp` is not a browser built-in. If you don't define it yourself then it won't be defined. Frames are irrelevant to that problem.

Perhaps you intended to first:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Oh... you are right... and I'm sleeping... so easy!thanks